# how to add names for column in sharepoint after programmatically uploading document

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I can upload documents into sharepoint via following code. My document library has 3 mandatory columns, "Project Title", etc. Whats the code to ensure that when I have successfully uploaded the document, the column data are reflected too.

Thank you!

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPSite mySite = SPContext.Current.Site;
        SPWeb myWeb = mySite.OpenWeb();
        DocumentAttached(myWeb);
    }

    //The Function for uploading a File in a Document Library is Below:
    public void DocumentAttached(SPWeb site)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            SPFolder folder = site.GetFolder("Innovation Submission");
            SPFileCollection files = folder.Files;
            Stream fStream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream; //path of the file to upload
            byte[] contents = new byte[fStream.Length];
            fStream.Position = 0;
            fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
            fStream.Close();
            string Filename = FileUpload1.FileName;
            string URL = SPContext.Current.Site.Url + "/RIDepartment/Innovation%20Submission/" + Filename;
            SPFile currentFile = files.Add(URL, contents);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assing your custom fileds after uploading a document, you can use SPFile.Item property i.e.:

```
SPListItem item = currentFile.Item;
item["Project Title"]="New title";
item.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for the Add method overloads that take a Hashtable as a parameter. You can use this to pass meta-data column values.